# How do I handle Canvas.Top change event in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, attached-properties

I have an element positioned on `Canvas` using attached properties `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`. Then using animations the element is moved to different set of coordinates, like this:

```
DoubleAnimation left = new DoubleAnimation( oldLeft, newLeft );
DoubleAnimation top = new DoubleAnimation( oldTop, newTop );

element.BeginAnimation( Canvas.LeftProperty, left );
element.BeginAnimation( Canvas.TopProperty, top );
```

Is there a way to receive events whenever `Canvas.Top` or `Canvas.Left` is changed? Preferably without relation to animation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One can [catch attached property changed event](http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2009/07/13/how-to-get-notifications-in-attached-properties.aspx) using `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`'s `AddValueChanged` method:

```
var descriptor 
    = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty( 
        Canvas.LeftProperty, typeof( YourControlType ) 
      );
descriptor.AddValueChanged( this, OnCanvasLeftChanged );
```